# Setup apache server

Tags: apache

I am completely new to all things apache, and thought I'd try a tutorial for fun. I have followed [this simple one](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-and-configure-apache#0) step for step multiple times, but my web browser always fails to "connect to the server at ". At this point I have installed apache2 properly, but can't get anything else than the default to work. Whenever I try to set up my own example.com (or other name) I only get the failure to connect to the server.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, so I would appreciate any thoughts on what I am missing. I have done nothing outside what is in the linked tutorial. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should make sure that your domain name is properly pointed to the server where you installed Apache.

Comment: @RoseHosting Thank you for your comment. The tutorial didn't mention that I had to disable the default server apart from enabling the new one. After disabling 000-default (or whatever it is called) and enabling my example.com it seems to work.